# Rotation of a volume tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, rotation, operators, tensor

I'm trying to apply a rotation to a 4 dimensional tensor in Tensorflow. I have a **tensor** of dimension `(batch_size, x_length, y_length, z_length)` and I've **a rotation matrix** `(3,3)`, how can I apply a rotation to the whole volume with tf operators ?

Thanks a lot for your help !